RabbitMQ, 2 Exchanges, 2 queues, one routing key
I have two rabbitMQ direct exchanges (AAExchange, SSExchange).
Each one has their own queue:

AAExchange, AAQueue
SSExchange, SSQueue

How come if I subscribe to MissionChanged on my channel which only has SSExchange, SSQueue.
And publish MissionChange my AA channel, how come SS "hears" it? It seems since that is bound to a different exchange, he shouldn't hear it, even if it is the same routing key, albeit from a different exchange.
